# Spring profiles: Which <beans> element should be parsed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I have the following configuration in my spring context:

```
<beans profile="!prof1" >
     <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
                <security:authentication-provider ref="1" />
                <security:authentication-provider ref="2" />
                <security:authentication-provider ref="3" />
            </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>

<beans profile="prof1" >
     <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
                <security:authentication-provider ref="0" />
                <security:authentication-provider ref="1" />
                <security:authentication-provider ref="2" />
                <security:authentication-provider ref="3" />
            </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

There is question which `<beans>` elements will be parsed take into account:
that **prof1** and **prof2** profiles are activated.

It looks like it always choose this one `<beans profile="prof1" >`, but not sure why it does not choose another one `<beans profile="!prof1" >`. Can I relay that it always will choose `<beans>` without exclamation mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Javadoc for Profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) states that

> If a given profile is prefixed with the NOT operator (!), the annotated component will be registered if the profile is not active

(The [spring-beans XSD](https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd) states the same for XML bean definitions but is harder to read.)

As I understand this, only **prof1** is looked at for the beans element with **profile="!prof1"**. That you also activate **prof2** is not relevant for this bean definition.

Comment: Thanks Michael for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

If your active profile is prof1 and prof2 the following will be active

```
<beans profile="prof1" >
 <security:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
            <security:authentication-provider ref="0" />
            <security:authentication-provider ref="1" />
            <security:authentication-provider ref="2" />
            <security:authentication-provider ref="3" />
        </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Thanks Essex! Could you please share some doc references why namely this profile will be chosen? Because currently, I see that spring choose this element <beans profile="prof1" >, but not sure that it will be always true.

Comment: I didn't look at the documentation, I ran a test.  I didn't realise it worked like that!  It does what you expect, i.e. !prof1 will be active for a profile of test.